# In quali casi si usano i verbi riferire e riportare intransitivamente e transitivamente?

Tags: grammar, verbs, word-choice, prepositions

"Le ho appena parlato e mi ha riferito/riportato l'accaduto"

"Le ho appena parlato  mi ha riferito/riportato dell'infortunio del mio collega di lavoro"

Ora, io nello scrivere queste frasi sono andato a orecchio e non ho seguito un vero e proprio criterio per stabilire se il verbo si usasse in modo transitivo o meno.

Ho provato a ripetermi le due frasi con o senza la preposizione "di" e ho scelto la soluzione che mi è risultata più naturale in entrambi gli specifici contesti.

La mia domanda è questa:

C'è un criterio da seguire secondo il quale si usa o l'una o l'altra costruzione verbale oppure si ha libera scelta e va bene l'uso sia intransitivo che transitivo in tutti i contesti frasali?

Answer (score 1):

Come *riportato* da [Corriere](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/R/riferire.shtml) per quanto riguarda il verbo **riferire**, teoricamente ci sarebbero leggere differenze d'uso. Nel parlato (ma pure nello scritto in realtà) si trovano entrambe le forme usate intercambiabilmente.

Quindi sì, il criterio c'è, ma è possibile usare la forma che meglio si addice al concetto che si vuole esprimere.

> v.tr. [sogg-v-arg-prep.arg]
>
> - Riportare, **raccontare ad altri quanto** si è venuti a conoscere: r. l'accaduto al responsabile; freq. con l'arg. diretto espresso da
>   frase (introd. da che): riferirono al dottore che il caso era grave
> - **Mettere in relazione**, collegare qlco. ad altro: r. il fatto a motivi di tipo diverso
>
> v.intr. (aus. avere) [sogg-v-prep.arg-prep.arg]
>
> - **Presentare a qlcu. una relazione** o un rapporto scritto su qlco.: la commissione riferirà al consiglio sui propri lavori; con il secondo
>   arg. sottinteso, fare un rapporto a un superiore: riferirò al
>   direttore

Comment: Giusto per pedanteria: è ospitato nel sito del Corriere, ma si tratta del dizionario Sabatini-Coletti.